# Adding content to menu items

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've made some menus, but can't figure out how to set the actual page content for these menu items once clicked. Cheers.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var menu = app.createMenuBar();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler();

  var menuUsers = menu.addItem('Users', handler).addSeparator().setId('users');
  var menuPending = menu.addItem('Pending Submissions', handler).addSeparator().setId('pending');

  app.add(menu);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you would have some main panel that is your main display. Let's call it `main-display"`.

The handler for each menu item executes a function when the menu item is clicked. This function can do anything (say, highlight some text, or pull up a toolbar, or save the file). It doesn't necessarily have to change the whole display. A menu bar is like the `File` menu or `Edit` or whatever you'd like.

You would have to define a ServerHandler that handles each different menu item being clicked.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var menu = app.createMenuBar();
  var handlerUsers = app.createServerHandler("showUsers");
  var handlerPending = app.createServerHandler("showPending");

  var menuUsers = menu.addItem('Users', handlerUsers).addSeparator().setId('users');
  var menuPending = menu.addItem('Pending Submissions', handlerPending).addSeparator().setId('pending');

  app.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(menu).add(app.createSimplePanel().setId("main-display")));
  return app;
}
```

Then have some functions

```
function showUsers() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var main = app.getElementById("main-display");
  //do whatever you need to display your main panel
  return app;
}
```

*Similar function for showPending*.

Instead, if you'd like a bunch of different content panels, look into using TabPanel. I feel like this is more of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - I decided to go with the TabPanel.